# Multiple source directories in middleman

Tags: ruby-on-rails, build, middleman

I have a few projects with common files, so I have made `source/shared` directory for them.
File structure looks like:

```
.
├── config.rb
├── build
├── source
│   ├── project-1
│   │   ├── index.html.slim
│   │   ├── js
│   │   │   ├── _templates.js.coffee
│   │   │   └── main.js.coffee
│   │   ├── layouts
│   │   │   └── layout.slim
│   ├── project-2
│   │   ├── index.html.slim
│   │   ├── js
│   │   │   ├── _templates.js.coffee
│   │   │   └── main.js.coffee
│   │   ├── layouts
│   │   │   └── layout.slim
│   └── shared
│       └── js
│           ├── vendor
│           │   ├── _json2.js
│           │   ├── html5shiv.js
```

Here I want `source/shared/js/vendor/html5shiv.js` to be in build directory, like main.js script.

When I am building project-1, build directory looks like:

```
build
├── index.html
├── js
│   ├── main-088a2c74.js
```

And with all that, can I somehow include shared files in build?

Comment: Are you suggesting it should be possible to individually build the projects? Because, if so, I'm very interested in this use case.

Comment: I am able to build projects individually by using MM_SOURCE environment variable.
`MM_SOURCE="source/project-1" middleman server`